# admin on rest custom filter

Tags: reactjs, filter, admin-on-rest

I am trying to add a custom filter to my List view. Before, I have managed to create custom input with a redux-form's Field component and used this in both Edit and Create view. Now when I try to use this same concept in the Filter component, it seems like the props are undefined. I do not know why. The reason I want to create a custom filter, is to filter with =gte= and =lte= on a timestamp.

What I want: A custom input where I can validate and do some calculations on a timestamp and then search for it with =gte= and =lte=.

Answer (score 1):

I share with you a component that works for me:

### DateBetweenInput.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
 import { DateInput } from 'react-admin'
 import { addField } from 'ra-core'

class DateBetweenInput extends Component {
  render () {
    const styles = {
      row: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
      }
    }

    const { resource, source } = this.props

    return (
      <span style={styles.row}>
        <DateInput
          source={`${source}.gt`}
          label={`resources.${resource}.fields.${source}_gt`}
        />
        &nbsp;
        <DateInput
          source={`${source}.lt`}
          label={`resources.${resource}.fields.${source}_lt`}
        />
      </span>
    )
  }
}

DateBetweenInput.defaultProps = {
  addLabel: true,
  label: 'createdAt'
}

export default addField(DateBetweenInput)
```

### Then use on your filters:

```
const PostFilter = (props) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <DateBetweenInput source='createdAt' alwaysOn />
  </Filter>
)
```

This feature is now an open issue on GitHub https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/817